# Uploading a simple form to Java Spring

Tags: javascript, java, spring

I'm simply trying to pass a text input and a file to Java but without success.
The formData seems to be working because I read the formData elements and all seems to be there. I just can't pass it to Java.

> HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Current request is not a multipart request

HTML

```
<form id="creationForm" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input id="testName" class="form-control" name="testName">
  <input type="file" name="fileUpload" id="fileUpload"/>
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var files = [];

  $('#fileUpload').change(function (event) {
    files = event.target.files;
  });

  $('#btnSubmit').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('creationForm'));
    console.log(files[0]);
    $.ajax({
      type: 'get',
      url: '/upload/testCase',
      data: formData,
      enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      success: function (result) {
      },
      error: function () {
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload/testCase", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody void uploadTestCase(@RequestParam("fileUpload") MultipartFile file ) {
    //TestCases.upload(file);
    System.out.println(file);
}
```

Spring XML included bean

```
<bean id="multipartResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're using the wrong http-method. Try to use **post** instead of **get**? That might solve it.

Spring:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload/testCase" , method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

JQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    ...
    ...
)};
```

Comment: You can also use `@PostMapping("/upload/testCase")`. Strictly equivalent and more concise.

Comment: If I put the post method in all of them I get that it cant use get method. this is so strange

Comment: @user9176898 Maybe you should use `<form method="post">` instead then. And replace the type in your ajax query from get to post.

Comment: Actually, the more I'm reading, the more things I see that should be changed.

Comment: I mean that I had all 3 post before.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/, this is the way your form should be defined to upload a file:

HTML

```html
<form id="creationForm" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/upload/testCase">
  <input id="fileName" class="form-control" name="name">
  <input id="fileUpload" type="file" name="fileUpload"/>
  <button class="form-control">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Java

```java
@PostMapping("/upload/testCase")
public void uploadTestCase(@RequestParam("fileUpload") MultipartFile file) {
    System.out.println(file);
}
```

In theory, you shouldn't need Javascript code for that.
But maybe you don't want the form to directly post your data, do you?